# Function to display returned results count isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery checkbox filter works normally:

http://jsfiddle.net/EducateYourself/Lmehmj26/3/

Under checkbox form I want to show the number of results. It is 7 by default.

When I filter the results, it does not show the correct number of displayed results.

Could you please help me to find my mistake?

I commented the lines in my jsfiddle code where I added variable n to achieve the result I want.

```
$('.category').on('change', function () {
    var n; //declare variable n
    var category_list = [];
    $('#filters :input:checked').each(function () {
        var category = $(this).val();
        category_list.push(category);
    });
    if (category_list.length == 0) {
        $('.resultblock').show();
    } else {
        $('.resultblock').hide();
        });

        $('#count').text(n); // change the results qunatity
    }
});
```

Comment: Your count is combing the results of each individual search. You'd need to account for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting doubles, a very easy fix is to add a check for visibility in your for loop like so

```
for (i = 0; i < category_list.length; ++i) {
    if (itemArray.indexOf(category_list[i]) >= 0 && !$(self).is(":visible")) {
        $(self).show();
        n=n+1; //increase the value of n if found a result
    }
}
```

As shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmehmj26/5/), that works

As a sidenote, your numbering breaks when you've selected one or more checkboxes and then deselect all. To prevent this you should change your check if there's been any checkboxes checked to

```
if (category_list.length == 0) {
        $('.resultblock').show();
        $('#count').text($('.resultblock').length);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are incrementing `n` multiple times for a single element if it contains multiple matching tags.

You should only increment `n` once, at most, for each element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktjts7s4/)

```
$('.resultblock').each(function() {
  var item = $(this).data('tag'),
    itemArray = item.split(' '),
    hasTag = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < category_list.length; ++i) {
    if (itemArray.indexOf(category_list[i]) >= 0) {
      hasTag = true;
    }
  }

  if (hasTag) {
    $(this).show();
    n++; // Only increment n once, at most, for each element.
  }
});
```

Here is a cleaner, simplified version of your code:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ws7yb5a/)

```
$('.category').on('change', function() {
  var categoryList = $('#filters :input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  var count = 0;

  $('.resultblock').hide().each(function() {
    var itemTagsArray = $(this).data('tag').split(' ');
    var hasTag = false;

    categoryList.forEach(function(tag) {
      if (itemTagsArray.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
        hasTag = true;
      }
    });

    if (hasTag) {
      $(this).show();
      count++;
    }
  });

  $('#count').text(count);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works now but when check all the checkboxes and then uncheck all of them, it does not show 7

Comment: @EducateYourself I have the solution to that in my sidenote ;) That said, this answer is probably 'cleaner' then mine

Comment: @EducateYourself See the update. I refactored the code and shortened it.